# Ubuntu not booting as a result of choosing the third option in wubi

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2, wubi

I am trying to install ubuntu 13.04 alongside windows.I have created a live-usb and in windows 7 , in wubi I choose the third option , that is helping me with ubuntu boot. When I restarted my pc, It gave me that, `completing installation, press 'esc' now for more boot options`. And after installing complete ubuntu that option doesn't seem to go away and when I choose to boot ubuntu in the boot menu , I again come to the live-session. I tried installing ubuntu again, this time the installer detects both the OS.I reinstalled the OS. But same problem. again in the live-session.

EDIT: During both the installation, I removed the usb just after restarting.If it has something to do with, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The third Wubi option is to help you boot the DVD/USB. This is e.g. if you don't have the ability to override your BIOS boot options. Most modern computers can do this with e.g. pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> when the computer starts, or <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter BIOS and modify the boot device order.
But in any case, when you use Wubi in this way, it's the same as booting the live environment.

Once you see the Ubuntu Desktop there will be an icon (top left on the Unity launcher) that is *Install Ubuntu*. **If** you click that you can install a normal dual boot. **Note** this is not a Wubi install, but a normal install that partitions your hard drive and installs the Grub bootloader to the drive MBR. If you don't install, then no changes are made. i.e. if you boot to the live environment and then shut down, nothing changes. The *Windows boot manager* entry is still there, but Ubuntu hasn't been installed, either with Wubi or normally. You still need that USB to boot.

The Wubi *boot helper* as it's called, added an entry in the *Windows Boot Manager*. This remains until you go to the Control Panel, Add or remove programs, and double click on *Ubuntu* to uninstall it.

PS. The Wubi *boot helper* is seldom used, tested, and poorly documented. I've used it with a CD a while ago, but not a USB. There may be some inaccuracies in the above, but most of it should be correct.